# Xamarin read from Azure EventHub

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-eventhub

I'm using the frameworks "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs (2.0.0)" and "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor (2.0.1)" to read from the azure notification hub. It works by running the app on the iPhone X iOS 11.2 Simulator but if I try to run the app on my iPhone 6s iOS 11.3 device - the app doesn't connect with the eventhub.

This is my code to connect with the eventhub:

```
public async Task StartReadingFromHub () {

_eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost (
    EhEntityPath,
    PartitionReceiver.DefaultConsumerGroupName,
    EhConnectionString,
    StorageConnectionString,
    LeaseContainerName);

var options = new EventProcessorOptions () {
    MaxBatchSize = 10
};

await _eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor> (options);
}
```

This is my EventProcessor:

```
public class SimpleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor {        

        public Task CloseAsync (PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason) {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task OpenAsync (PartitionContext context) {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task ProcessErrorAsync (PartitionContext context, Exception error) {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    public Task ProcessEventsAsync (PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages) {

        foreach (var eventData in messages) {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);
            var alert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Alert> (data);
            HubMessages.receivedMessages.Add (alert);
        }

        return context.CheckpointAsync ();
    }
}
```

And the OpenAsync Function will never enter.

Comment: Is event `ProcessErrorAsync ()` called? Did it throw some exceptions?

Comment: Is the issue resolved? Have you tried using browser in Iphone 6s to connect to the event hub?